# CSS shape semicircle alignment problem with border of rectangle

Tags: html, css

I want to create a shape using CSS. The only problem I am facing is the alignment of semicircle with the border of rectangle which is not working out properly.
I am attaching the image of what I have done till now. Can anybody help me out to fix these alignment problem. Thank you.

[image]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

    #talkbubble {
      width: 120px;
      height: 80px;
      border: 4px solid #4C4C4C;
      position: relative;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #talkbubble:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 42%;
      left: -11.6px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 15px;
      border: 4px solid #4C4C4C;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-top-left-radius: 30px;
      border-top-right-radius: 30px; 
      background-color: white;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

  #talkbubble:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 42%;
        right: -12px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 15px;
        border: 4px solid #4C4C4C;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
        background-color: white;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
```

```html
<div id="talkbubble"></div>
```

Comment: hmm but i dont see that problem at all when i run the code

Comment: @coder If you zoom a little bit and check alignment between semicircle and border of rectangle, you'll see it. You will also see light border on it

Comment: try increasing the width of  `::before` and `::after` a liitle bit, it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add overflow hidden in case, and a full circle?

```css
.ticket-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.ticket {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ticket::before,
.ticket::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.ticket::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket-outer">
<div class="ticket"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently with one element:

```css
.ticket {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:20px;
  border:8px solid;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 38px at right,#000 95%,#0000),
    radial-gradient(circle 38px at left ,#000 95%,#0000);
  background-origin:border-box;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 30px at right,#0000 95%,#000) right,
    radial-gradient(circle 30px at left ,#0000 95%,#000) left;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket"></div>
```