# How can add two rounds shapes in a rectangle?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've a rectangle parent and I need to add two circles at left and right vertically centered.
Here's the design I'm trying to code: 
[image: design to code]

Here's the design I coded so far: 
[image: coded]

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Offer = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="sm:py-6 py-4  flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly sm:px-12 px-6 m-4 my-6 bg-white rounded-md relative filter drop-shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex flex-row w-full items-center divide-x-2 divide-dashed divide-gray-400">
            <div className="flex-none sm:pr-8 mr-2">
              <svg
                className="w-12 h-12 flex-none"
                fill="#3BB44B"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-auto flex-col text-center space-y-2 pl-1">
              <h3 className="font-semibold">BUT 1 GET 1 FREE</h3>
              <p className="text-sm break-words">
                Buy one and get one free when your order value exceeds
              </p>
              <span className="text-sm text-yellow-500 font-medium">
                SHOW MORE
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span className="w-10 h-10 absolute bg-gray-100 shadow-inner -right-5 transform -translate-y-2/4 top-2/4 rounded-full"></span>
          <span className="w-10 h-10 absolute bg-gray-100 -left-5  shadow-inner transform -translate-y-2/4 top-2/4 rounded-full"></span>
        </div>
      </>
    );
}

export default Offer
```

I've used two `span` elements on parent div with `absolute` position. I've used inner shadow but it still does not looks like the design i want to achieve.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345816/8620333 (simply remove the border and background and keep the mask)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I removed the background I can't see the circcles.

Comment: I meant remove the background I am using and use your own, a simple color

Comment: Did that. But I wanted the shadow around. Still not looking like the design I mentioned.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u0kcmjfo/

Comment: Your code works fine but somehow I am loosing my box-shadow. here's my code:
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #000);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle 1.3rem at right, #0000 95%, #000) right,
    radial-gradient(circle 1.3rem at left, #0000 95%, #000) left;
  -webkit-mask-size: 51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
display: flex;
background-color: white;
position: relative;
 and some margin and padding. I didn't specified the height and width. and if I set mask to none. the box shadow appears

Comment: the filter need to be applied to a parent container, not the same element so you have to add an extra wrapper

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want those mask circle to at almost bottom not center, how can I do that and let me know if you have any good resource or article on mask. Thanks

Comment: the mask are using radial-gradient so it's not really about mask, simply read about radial gradient and how to adjust the different values, it should be quite easy